# Broadcast an array by N dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays,

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones(100)
b = np.ones(1000).reshape(100, 1, 10)
dims_difference = b.ndim - a.ndim
```

Assume that `b` has more dimensions than `a`, but not necessarily two. I want to extend `a` to make sure the operation `a + b` works as intended (over the first axis). When I know that it is two, I can do that by hard-coding:

```
a = a[:, None, None]
```

How can I do this in a general way when the number of dimensions that need to be added at the and are contained in `dims_difference`?

Comment: `.reshape(100,1,1)` does the same thing. Look at the code for `expand_dims` for more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

One - not so elegant - solution based on @hpaulj's comment is the following:

```
for i in np.arange(dims_difference)+1:
    a = np.expand_dims(a, i)
```

Comment: In new enough versions you can provide `np.expand_dims(a, (1,2))`.  And elaborating on my comment, note that `expand_dims` ends with `return a.reshape(shape)`, with most of the code creating that `shape` list.

Comment: There is also ```a[(slice(None), *(None,)*dims_difference)]``` if you want a one-liner.